# Correct preposition after the word encouragement

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I am writing a paper and I am not quite sure about the correct preposition that comes after the word encouragement.

> "Consequently, there was always encouragement `towards, for, to` any
>   kind of art forms in the house."

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You could always rephrase it to avoid the decision altogether: *Consequently, all forms of art in the house were always encouraged.*

Comment: Yes, that is also possible.

Comment: Out of these three, certainly *for*. The other two are dead in the water.

Comment: thanks RedDwigHt. Would you elaborate a little further than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion that you have regarding the usage of to and for with the word encouragement is too obvious because both are accepted but according to the context that prevails. for instance 
1. I would like to say a few words encouragement to my friend.
2. I said some words of encouragement for my students

Comment: Ok, so are you saying in the context of my sentence, the correct preposition is towards?